# How to save through parent table on one-to-one relationship over primary key

Tags: orm, railo

I am trying to saveentity with first table where tables linked with one-to-one relationship on primary key. Here is code that I am trying,

**tbl6.cfc**

```
component name="tbl6" persistent='true'  accessors="true"{
    property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
    property name="col";
    property name="tbl7" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="tbl7";
}
```

**tbl7.cfc**

```
component name="tbl7" persistent='true'  accessors="true"{
    property name="tbl7id" fieldtype="id" generator="foreign" params="{property='tbl6'}";
    property name="tbl6" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="tbl6" constrained="true";
    property name="col";
}
```

**index.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
    ormreload();
    objt6 = entityNew("tbl6",{"col":"tbl6"});
    objt7 = entityNew("tbl7",{"col":"tbl7"});
    objt6.settbl7(objt7);
    objt7.settbl6(objt6);
    entitysave(objt6);
</cfscript>
```

In above case ORM only save record for tbl6, but if I change entitysave argument to objt7 it store record for both table. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying this in RAILO 4.1

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I got that, I just need to add cascade="all" in property of tbl7 in tbl6.cfc

```
property name="tbl7" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="tbl7" cascade="all";
```

I just keep question to help others.